# Design doubts about RESTful API design with filtering logic based on user role?

Tags: rest

I'm facing the following API requirements:

1. A multi-cart system design i.e. each user can create **multiple carts** (just one "active" at any time)
2. **Regular user** can see only carts created by him
3. **Admin users** can see all carts including carts created by other users

Now, from API point of view, I can see two solutions:

#### A) Multiple cart endpoints

- `GET /api/carts` returns all carts of all users (invoked only by admins)
- `GET /api/me/carts` returns only carts owned by the current authenticated user

With this solution:

- Too much logic from the client side; imagine a page showing carts, when user is an admin, the `/api/carts` should be invoked instead of `/api/me/carts`; in addition, major UI changes and conditional should be involved (show cart owner, etc.)
- How cart should be updated? `PATCH /api/carts/1` vs `PATCH /api/me/carts/1`
- Filtering/pagination logic should be repeated for each endpoint

#### B) Single endpoint with server-side automatic filtering

- `GET /api/carts` returns all carts, filtered based on user permissions; i.e. return carts owned for regular users, all carts for admin users.

With this solution:

- ✅ DRY, not repeating filtering/pagination logic
- Maybe minor client UI conditionals

*So to the question: is there any other option? I'm pretty sure this is a common task but I can't find so much suggestions or examples.*

Answer (score 0):

There probably isn't a single "canonical" answer here: what you really have is a problem in resource design, and both REST and HTTP are deliberately agnostic about how you design your resource model.

---

Having the same information available via multiple resources is *normal*.

> For example, the "authors' preferred version" of an academic paper is a mapping whose value changes over time, whereas a mapping to "the paper published in the proceedings of conference X" is static. These are two distinct resources, even if they both map to the same value at some point in time. The distinction is necessary so that both resources can be identified and referenced independently. A similar example from software engineering is the separate identification of a version-controlled source code file when referring to the "latest revision", "revision number 1.2.7", or "revision included with the Orange release." -- [Fielding, 2000](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_2_1_1)

But normal doesn't necessarily mean "free" - you are looking at some duplication in that case, and there is the interesting problem of what happens when one resource is changed?

---

In an ideal world, resource identity and access control are unrelated concerns:  if Admin wants to see the representation that Bob is looking at, then Admin sends a request targeting the same resource identifier but with Admin authorization, and (assuming access control allows Admin to interact with the resource) the Admin receives the same representation that Bob did.

And similarly, if you want a separate representation of the same information available to Admin only, you create a separate resource with a more appropriate access control policy.

When you do that, as far as HTTP / general purpose clients are concerned, you now have two completely different resources.  The fact that the representations of these resources are near duplicates of each other is an implementation detail hidden behind the facade of your API.

An important side effect of this approach: when you share a URI with someone else, they get the *same* experience you do, not a completely different experience because their credentials differ from yours.  You can bookmark that experience.  You can review the resource identifiers in the access logs, and know which experience was delivered.

---

But yes, that might be more work.  Welcome to the world of trade-offs.

This is why I don't believe you are going to find a canonical answer: the "best practice" is going to depend on how much value you deliver via each approach, verses what the costs are of each approach (where the responsible cost calculation would also include externalities).  And the answers to those questions depends on local context.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an OAuth perspective on your question, focused on separating client and API concerns.

**SECURE RESOURCE URLs**

I would argue that when security is involved, it is standard for REST collection URLs to always return different results per user. So the results of this operation will involve filtering based on who the user is and what their privileges are:

```
GET /api/carts
```

Similarly, this URL should always involve a check that the user has access to cart 1:

```
PATCH /api/carts/1
```

**API VIEWPOINT**

In OAuth architectures, APIs receive a JWT access token on every request. In some cases, the client sends a cookie or reference token that is converted at the API gateway, but the API receives a JWT.

Since the API validates a JWT on every request, the user identity and any other claims, such as roles, can be trusted afterwards. The API endpoint's job is then to simply filter the data and return items to the client. For an admin user, this might be based on a claim of `role=admin`.

APIs should avoid receiving secure values in URL path segments, where a man in the middle could potentially replace them. This might reduce the RESTfulness of your design, but is an important consideration.

**UI VIEWPOINT**

The above may be insufficient for an end-to-end solution. For example, maybe the UI needs to render items differently for an admin user, eg to show who owns the item.

Therefore it is common for the UI to also ask an API for claims it needs about the user identity, via a second API endpoint. In OAuth this can be the User Info endpoint in some cases, or a custom API endpoint in others. The claims returned should be tailored to what the UI needs, eg they might include a claim of `is_admin=true`.

**SUMMARY**

I would recommend thinking your REST design through from the three viewpoints of the API, the client and security. With this approach, clean separation often enables you to write the most natural code in each component.

If a resource had a completely different meaning in an admin context, I would use different API endpoints. This does not seem to be the case in your scenario though, so I would avoid the `/me` endpoints.

Answer (score 0):

For this question, there is no specific answer to this.

I prefer to go with the second approach. why?

1. no duplicate code for searching functionality
2. only one API for search functionality
3. easy to maintain and extend the functionality on the basis of some configuration

We implemented the same functionality in one of our services and used the **data fencing** concept. While retrieving the cart by ID, the API token should consist of the customer id as well as the role in the token for that API. On the basis of that, create the filters and make a query to the database. If there is no customer id then check the role for admin in the token and get all the cart from the database.